# how to set different replication_do_db for different channel in MYSQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, replication

i have issue to set different replication_do_db replication in each channel.
so i want to set like this : replicate_do_db=db1 for channel a and replicate_do_db=db2 for channel b 
as far i know we can use CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_DO_DB = (d1) FOR CHANNEL channel_1 in mysql 8.
but how if we use in mysql 5.7?
any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have one master and multiple slaves, each one intended for a different database. 
You can replicate each database on master to a different slave by specifying this in slave my.cnf

Slave1 (channel_1)

```
[mysqld]
replicate-do-db=channel_1
```

Slave2 (channel_2)

```
[mysqld]
replicate-do-db=channel_2
```

And so on.
Note that each slave will still get ALL binary logs relayed (i.e. each database entire data) but selectively apply them in the slave server as per the database specified in the my.cnf.

This is an afterthought in case your question is about how to specify multiple databases in a replicate-do-db option, you can do so comma separated -

```
[mysqld]
replicate-do-db=channel_1,channel_2
```